# PHP 7.4 Configuration File on CentOS 7

Tags: php, nginx, centos, php-7, php-7.4

I have **PHP 5.6** on my server with *nginx*, and want to install **PHP 7.4** to do some tests in advance. I followed [this guide](https://www.tecmint.com/run-multiple-websites-with-different-php-versions-in-nginx/) (changing **PHP 7.1** to **7.4**) and now I have my default **PHP 5.6** and **PHP 7.4**.

The problem is, there is no `php-fpm74.sock` socket file in the `/var/run/php-fpm` directory. And I couldn't manage to find configuration files for **PHP 7.4**. There is path `/opt/remi/php74/root/` where the configs supposed to be but the folder is empty. I've tried to copy `php-fpm.conf` and `php-fpm.d` there but it doesn't help.

Comment: That's not a programming question and as such more suitable to e.g. superuser.com.

Comment: See /etc/opt/remi/phpxx directory